# Regex Expression not matching correctly

Tags: python, regex

I'm tackling a python challenge problem to find a block of text in the format xXXXxXXXx (lower vs upper case, not all X's) in a chunk like this:

jdskvSJNDfbSJneSfnJDKoJIWhsjnfakjn

I have tested the following RegEx and found it correctly matches what I am looking for from this site (http://www.regexr.com/):

'([a-z])([A-Z]){3}([a-z])([A-Z]){3}([a-z])'

However, when I try to match this expression to the block of text, it just returns the entire string:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: example = 'jdskvSJNDfbSJneSfnJDKoJIWhsjnfakjn'

In [3]: expression = re.compile(r'([a-z])([A-Z]){3}([a-z])([A-Z]){3}([a-z])')

In [4]: found = expression.search(example)

In [5]: print found.string
jdskvSJNDfbSJneSfnJDKoJIWhsjnfakjn
```

Any ideas? Is my expression incorrect? Also, if there is a simpler way to represent that expression, feel free to let me know. I'm fairly new to RegEx.

Comment: That chuck of text has no sub strings that match.

Comment: What text are you running it on?  If you run it on the example you give (uBRrJZ...), then you'll get None, because as hwnd says there are no groups like that in that string.

Comment: Right, I know the example I gave does not have it. The full text is 100,000 characters long, so I only pasted a sample. There should be exactly one match. Just edited to a different sample that does have that pattern (nJDKoJIWh)

Comment: Have you tried `expression.search(text)`?

Comment: @emilylinndb: I can't reproduce your problem.  When I run that code with that string as `text` I get the matching text just fine.  Can you create a simplified, self-contained example with sample data that actually shows the problem?

Comment: @BrenBarn see new edits

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the match group instead of the string attribute.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'jdskvSJNDfbSJneSfnJDKoJIWhsjnfakjn'
>>> rgx = re.compile(r'[a-z][A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}[a-z]')
>>> found = rgx.search(s).group()
>>> print found
nJDKoJIWh
```

Comment: That worked! Why does returning .group() work but not .string()?

Answer (score 0):

The `string` attribute always returns the string passed as input to the match.  This is clearly [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.string):

> **string**
>
> The string passed to match() or search().

The problem has nothing to do with the matching, you're just grabbing the wrong thing from the match object.  Use `match.group(0)` (or `match.group()`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on `xXXXxXXXx` if you want upper letters with len 3 and lower with len 1 between them this is what you want :

```
([a-z])(([A-Z]){3}([a-z]))+
```

also you can get your `search` function with `group()`

```
print expression.search(example).group(0)
```